Помогите с ошибкой aiogram 2x и кнопки
Я использую метод edit_message_caption(), и в reply_markup передаю markup с инлайн кнопками ( их изначально было 3), сейчас я просто добавил еще одну кнопку и он начал выдавать ошибку "aiogram.utils.exceptions.NetworkError: File too large for uploading. Check telegram api limits" в строке с edit_message_caption(). Кроме как добавлять кнопку я ничего не изменял
с чем это может быть связано? помогите пожалуйста
Также я заметил что если убрать одну кнопку из этих 3, и заменить её на кнопку другую кнопку ( которую я добавлял 4-ой) то опять будет срабатывать эта ошибка
вот код
markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
markup.row(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Назад', callback_data="back_-1"), types.InlineKeyboardButton("кнопка посередине", callback_data='nonecallback'), types.InlineKeyboardButton('Вперед', callback_data="forward_+1"))
markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Купить', callback_data=f"buy"))
await bot.edit_message_caption(callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id, caption=f"caption", parse_mode='html')
await bot.edit_message_reply_markup(callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id, reply_markup=markup)
( такой код у меня не работает, тексты я изменил если что, а если убрать markup.add - всё будет работать )
помогите прошуу

как задать хороший вопрос

Степа, вы превысили лимит телеграмм по длине поля callback_data.

Optional. Data to be sent in a callback query to the bot when the button is pressed, 1-64 bytes

Проверьте длину своего сообщения с учетом того, что буквы в кириллице занимают 2байта.

Спасибо за ваш ответ, но к сожалению это не помогло :( ( Я уменьшил длину поля callback_data, это не помогло )

Пришлите содержимое callback_data из кнопки, которую вы добавили.
